# How can I find the staging URL for an Azure deployment?

Tags: azure

I've got an automated build deploying to Azure. I'd like to know the staging URL.

Ideally I'd like to be able to assign a DNS to it so I don't have to distribute a new staging URL every time I deploy.

Otherwise, I'd like to be able to find the staging URL so I can distribute it automatically.

Any ideas?

Comment: Yeah, I wish Azure didn't generate a new GUID for every time you deployed to staging. I'm interested in learning about some workarounds.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? How do you use the GetDeployment API in this case? I need to be able to find the exact URL of the service to put in to its web.config file. Thanks, DL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presumably your automated deployment is using the Service Management API... you can just use the ["Get Deployment" method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee460804.aspx) to get the staging deployment's URL.

Comment: That'll do just fine. Thanks!